# Run gradle task after project is built with distribution plugin

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm using gradle 4.1
My project has five modules. After build I generate five jars in each module.
My goal is to create a zip archive and upload it to artifactory server.
I can only generate my zip deploy artifact with my jars only when build of other modules is complete. I see that it copies jars from libs directory, but I'm looking for a way to do this after the overall build of the project. I saw some examples with dependsOn, but it doesn't seem to be working.
Here is what I have:

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'

distributions {
   main {
     baseName = 'b-deploy'
     contents {
       from { "b-model/build/libs/b-model-${version}.jar" }
       from { "b-wsdl/build/libs/b-wsdl-${version}.jar" }
       from { "b-common/build/libs/b-common-${version}.jar" }
       from { "b-rest/build/libs/b-rest-${version}.jar" }
       from { "b-soap/build/libs/b-soap-${version}.jar" }
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom configuration to hold all you deployables:

```
configurations {
    deployable {
        transitive = false
    }
}
```

Gather everything you need in your ZIP in that configuration. Note how you can add third-party libraries here, if you need them:

```
dependencies {
    deployable project(path: ':a')
    deployable project(path: ':b')
    deployable 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0'
}
```

Then, create a task for that ZIP:

```
task deployableZIP(type: Zip) {
    dependsOn configurations.deployable

    baseName = 'gradle-deploy'
    destinationDir = buildDir

    configurations.deployable.collect {
        from it
    }
}
```

Finally, configure publishing:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        main(MavenPublication) {
            artifact source: deployableZIP, extension: 'zip'
        }
    }
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @madhead. Does `deployable` come with a plugin together?

Comment: You create it as a custom configuration as a first step here. The name is arbitrary.

Comment: when creating custom configuration, I need toextend her from other with `extendsFrom` correct? Or this is unnecessary?

Comment: Extending is not necessary. You should not extend `deployables` from any configuration in this case in order not to pollute it with extra artifacts (because you want to control what gets inside the ZIP).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [`finalizedBy`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:finalizer_tasks)?.

So in your example:

```
build.finalizedBy(distributions)
```