# Move publishing configuration to one place in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a project which has modules, my goal is to configure publishing after each module is built and after all modules are built, so I could create a zip file with all the jars inside and upload it as well. I do it in `subprojects` section and in outer section.

```
publishing {
  publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
      //my artifacts here
    }
  }
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "${artifactoryURL}"
      credentials {
        username = "${artifactoryUsername}"
        password = "${artifactoryPassword}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to move `repositories` configuration to one place, so I could avoid duplication of this configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you're creating your deployables in a top-level (root, parent) project, that does not have any sources.

> Is there a way to move repositories configuration to one place, so I could avoid duplication of this configuration?

Sure. Just use [`subprojects`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:subprojects(groovy.lang.Closure)), [`allprojects`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:allprojects(groovy.lang.Closure)) or generic [`configure`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#configure(java.lang.Iterable,%20groovy.lang.Closure)), depending on your needs:

```
allprojects {
  id 'maven-publish'

  publishing {
    repositories {
      maven {
        url "http://maven.repo"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will configure publishing for all the projects (be aware of that you may not want to publish everything).

For a projects with Java source you can configure publishing like usual:

```
subprojects {
  publishing {
      publications {
          main(MavenPublication) {
              from components.java

              artifact sourcesJar
              artifact javadocJar
          }
      }
  }
}
```

And for root project just configure deployments as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46286348/750510).

Comment: Is it important to mention `id 'maven-publish'` ?

Comment: I changed `id 'maven-publish'` to `apply plugin: 'maven-publish'` and now it is working.

Comment: Sure, that was a typo. `id 'maven-publish'` is for new `plugins` block.